# I have a dataset with columns: c(country, element, 1961, 1961flags, 1962, 1962 flags)

Tags: r

That goes on for until 2011. I know that 1961:2011 would assign all years in between, but is there a way to accommodate the separate flag column?

To be more specific, it is a csv file. I am reading in the data as

```
data <-read.csv("file", 
           col.names=(country, element, *would be 1961:2011 if there were no flag columns*),     header=True)
```

Comment: Could you show few lines of your dataset?  I assume that you don't have the `flag` column..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `paste0` to generate the names.

```
col.names = c(country, element, paste0(rep(1961:2011, each=2), c("", "flags")))
```

the `rep` call will generate:

```
  [1] 1961 1961 1962 1962 1963 1963 1964 1964 1965 1965 1966 1966 1967 1967 1968
 [16] 1968 1969 1969 1970 1970 1971 1971 1972 1972 1973 1973 1974 1974 1975 1975
 [31] 1976 1976 1977 1977 1978 1978 1979 1979 1980 1980 1981 1981 1982 1982 1983
 [46] 1983 1984 1984 1985 1985 1986 1986 1987 1987 1988 1988 1989 1989 1990 1990
 [61] 1991 1991 1992 1992 1993 1993 1994 1994 1995 1995 1996 1996 1997 1997 1998
 [76] 1998 1999 1999 2000 2000 2001 2001 2002 2002 2003 2003 2004 2004 2005 2005
 [91] 2006 2006 2007 2007 2008 2008 2009 2009 2010 2010 2011 2011
```

Note that I am using `each` and not `times` which would instead result in appending twice the sequence 1961:2011.